# Finding all available paths with a location connection list on Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, path-finding

Currently, I have a list of connected locations like the following example:

```
A|B  
A|C  
B|C  
B|E  
C|D    
C|Z
```

Which would mean a network like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbxCo.png)**

The goal would be, given a Start and End location, list all possible paths. So for example, given Start = A & End = Z, we'd have:

```
A-C-Z  
A-B-C-Z
```

Right now, I have the following code set up:

```
Sub run_report()
    Set euh = Sheets("Input")
    'B5 and D5 are the two locations to be connected
    If euh.Range("B5").Value <> "" And euh.Range("D5").Value <> "" Then
        Call worm(euh.Range("B5").Value, euh.Range("D5").Value, 1,  euh.Range("B5").Value & "|")
        ' "Hops" is where the available paths will be displayed
        Sheets("Hops").Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "Both locations need to be selected!"
    End If
End Sub

'Starting/Current location, End/Goal location, current number of connections used so far, used nodes/locations in this path
Sub worm(vstart As String, vend As String, vlvl As Integer, used As String)
    ' "DB" is the connection list database
    Set sdb = Sheets("DB")
    Set sh = Sheets("Hops")
    Dim target As String
    Dim vline As Integer

    ' Iterates through all available connections looking for the next step
    For a = 1 To sdb.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        If sdb.Range("A" & a).Value = vstart Or sdb.Range("B" & a).Value = vstart Then
            If sdb.Range("A" & a).Value = vstart Then
                target = sdb.Range("B" & a).Value
            Else
                target = sdb.Range("A" & a).Value
            End If


            If target = vend Then
                'Add successfull connection
                used = used & target
                vline = IIf(sh.Range("A2").Value <> "", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 2)
                sh.Range("A" & vline).Value = vlvl
                sh.Range("C" & vline).Value = used
            'If the current node/location hasn't been used so far
            ElseIf InStr(used, target) = 0 Then
                used = used & target & "|"
                Call worm(target, vend, (vlvl + 1), used)
            End If
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Right now the code works *mostly* as it should, **but I think the problem is that instead of the sub [worm] passing the arguments as temporary for each next recursion, the variables *vlvl* and *used* are being treated as a global**, so even when the code reaches a dead end path, the nodes that were used to get there are still being added for the next iterations, so the previous example would print out as:

A-B-C-[D] *(dead end)*-Z
*[**the entire previous line**]* + A-C- *[B-E](dead end 1)* *-[D](dead end 2)* - Z

Any ideas on how that could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that `used` is being treated as a global variable - it's that you're changing it before calling the recursive function. Try deleting `used = used & target & "|"` and changing the next line to `Call worm(target, vend, (vlvl + 1), used & target & "|")`.

Comment: I tried that too, but that makes Excel crash/not respond. I tried making the `used` argument being `ByVal`, but that results in the same problem.

Comment: Apparently you were right, the only problem was the size of the database i was dealing with. I tried the example one and it worked great. Not to find a way to make this work with a 120 connections list!